# JSONField model field in django: How to make it editable in django admin

Tags: python, django

How do I go about making a django model field of type JSONField editable in django admin?

Example Model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models

class AppModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    data = JSONField()
```

Example of data column in PostgreSQL:

```
data = {
  "debug": "on",
  "window": {
     "title": "Sample Data",
     "name": "main_window",
     "attr":[{"width": 500},{"height": 500}]
  },
  "widget": true
}
```

Examples, links to examples would be very much appreciated.